# How to retrieve data safe for prevent sql injections

Tags: php, mysql

I have my database and im retrieving data like below.But i need to retrieve them more secure for prevent by the sql injections.in my script im getting all the fields like below and in echo out in a place where i want to show the fields.
Please tell me a secure way to get them.Please help me,any help much appreciated.
And i want to use while function to retrieve all the data.Please help me

```
 <?php
 $getdata ="SELECT * FROM tblname ODER BY ";
$result = mysql_query($getdata);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$bookName    = $row['bookName'];
$timestamp  = $row['timestamp'];
$Country    = $row['Country'];
$Category   = $row['Category'];
$Price    = $row['Price'];
$Photo1name = $row['Photo1name'];
   ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SQL injection`](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php) can only be performed if you use user input.
So you are safe with that when you read from database. With your code you must use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), but I suggest using PDO and it's prepared statements to auto-escape values.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE name = :name ORDER BY');
$sth->execute([':name' => $_POST['name']]);
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
```

To sanitize your output try using [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) functions.

To prevent SQL injection you have to escape values:

```
$pdo = PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'iAmD4B3st!');
$sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO my_table (name, surname) VALUES (:name, :surname)");
$sql->execute([
    ':name' => isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '',
    ':surname' => isset($_POST['surname']) ? $_POST['surname'] : '',
]);
```

Comment: Im sanitizing input fields.
But im prefer to know it in scripting,not pdo,
I Dont know about PDO,
CAn you please tell me how to get all the data and display them in an div tag ?()
Thanks

Comment: @LeoneMaleash PDO is non-deprecated library to work with databases. `display them in an div tag`: `<div><?php echo $response['name']; ?></div>`

Comment: actually im stuck at this.Im getting opnly one row data as i echo the datas.

$getdataquery = mysql_query("SELECT `bookName`, `bookAccessLink`, `timestamp`, `Country`, `Category`, `Price`, `Photo1name` FROM tblname ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, 25");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getdataquery)){



$bookName   = $row['AdName'];
$bookAccessLink = $row['AdAccessLink'];
$timestamp  = $row['timestamp'];
$Country = $row['Country'];
$Category   = $row['Category'];
$Price    = $row['Price'];
$Photo1name = $row['Photo1name'];


}

Comment: @LeoneMaleash I think you are re-assigning values to same variables. Echo them in loop.

Comment: ok,i got it.Thank you for your great supporty.I fine your codes are very useful.